# PHP Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `')'' ...what to do?

Tags: php, parsing, session

```
<?php //login_success.php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'] = $myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

On runnig this I get the error

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `')'' in C:\wamp\www\a\l\login_success.php on line 4
```

Can someone help me out with this one, ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['username'] == $myusername)`

Answer (score 0):

I see an error at

isset()

You can either use

```
isset($_SESSION['username'])
```

or

```
if($_SESSION['username'] == $myusername)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try to get a value for `$_SESSION['username']` outside if statement.
Something like this

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```